# Is there any way to change response status code in apache httpd config

Tags: apache

As title, I want to use Apache httpd as proxy server, I'm looking for solution for below flow.

HTTP-POST→apache→server AA → response(200 OK）→apache→response(204 No Content)

Because in "server AA" not support return 204 code for this API, we can't change it.

Is there any way to config in httpd.conf, something like that

```
<Location "/test">
    ProxyPass http://serverAA/api/aaa
    ProxyPassReverse http://serverAA/api/aaa
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain serverAA "current httpd ip"
    RedirectMatch 204 [R=200,L]
</Location>
```